# Full Calendar v3 extending display beyond end of calendar year in List View

Tags: fullcalendar

Good morning!

I have a list view set up in full calendar and have noticed that it will not display events beyond the end of the year. With it being now mid-December, this is a bit of a problem for me. We have several event that should be displaying in this list. When I change the view to month I have to click the next month button to get next years events, but at least with that I do sucessfully see the events in question.

Is there a way for my list view calendars to roll-over and include next year entries as I approach the end of the current year?

Here is an excerpt of what I have that effects the display of my calendar:

```
    {url:'https://calendar.mydomain.com/services/id/38djsuw3hr-au8reh39dq/organization/1/department/13/',event_properties:{color:'#6a9b49'}},
]


function data_req (url, callback) {
    req = new XMLHttpRequest()
    req.addEventListener('load', callback)
    req.open('GET', url)
    req.send()
}   

function add_recur_events() {
    if (sources_to_load_cnt < 1) {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', expand_recur_events)
    } else {
        setTimeout(add_recur_events, 30)
    }
}

function load_ics(ics){
    data_req(ics.url, function(){
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', fc_events(this.response, ics.event_properties))
        sources_to_load_cnt -= 1
    })
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: '',
            center: '',
            right: '' //view options on top-right (supported by v2.9.1 currently)    
        },
        viewDisplay: function(view) {
            parent.setIframeHeight(iframeId) ;
          },
        eventClick: function(event) { 
            // opens events in a new window or tab
            window.open(event.url,);
            return false;

          },
         // eventDataTransform: function(rawEventData){
         //     return {title: rawEventData.Title
         //         };
         //     },

        defaultView: $(window).width() < 765 ? 'listYear':'listYear', //carryover code from full sized calendar
            nowIndicator: false, //show a marker for current time 
            eventLimit: 4, // allow "more" link when too many events
            fixedWeekCount: false, // have blank rows on a 6 or 7 row month
            listDayFormat: 'MMMM Do',
            listDayAltFormat: false,
            allDayDefault: false,
            noEventsMessage: "No Currently Scheduled Events"
        })

    sources_to_load_cnt = ics_sources.length
    for (ics of ics_sources) {
        load_ics(ics)
    }
    add_recur_events()
})
```

All I see is my "NoEventsMessage" text when in list view. If I create a test event the occurs prior to the end of the year it shows up in list view.

Any ideas on spanning calendar end?
thanks

[*Edit*: I should say that the link at the top is a JSON feed, so I am not using a prefilled list of events from within my script or from within an external file]

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I solved it.

1. I created a custom view entry for the specific default view called "list" and gave it a one year duration:

   `views: {
            list: {
                duration: { days:365 }
                   }
          },`
2. I reset my default view from the dynamic version I carried over from my full-sized calendar (since I am using this in a column anyway and the window width call is not needed):

   From:

   `defaultView: $(window).width() < 765 ? 'listYear':'listYear',`

   To:

   `defaultView: 'list',`

After doing those things my January entries for next year began to display in list view.

Here is what my display calls look like (*If someone wants to edit this to make it look prettier and more efficient, I don't mind :*).

```
ics_sources = [
        {url:'https://calendar.mydomain.com/services/id/38djsuw3hr-au8reh39dq/organization/1/department/13/',event_properties:{color:'#6a9b49'}},
]


function data_req (url, callback) {
    req = new XMLHttpRequest()
    req.addEventListener('load', callback)
    req.open('GET', url)
    req.send()
}   

function add_recur_events() {
    if (sources_to_load_cnt < 1) {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', expand_recur_events)
    } else {
        setTimeout(add_recur_events, 30)
    }
}

function load_ics(ics){
    data_req(ics.url, function(){
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', fc_events(this.response, ics.event_properties))
        sources_to_load_cnt -= 1
    })
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: false,

        viewDisplay: function(view) {
            parent.setIframeHeight(iframeId) ;
          },
        eventClick: function(event) { 
            // opens events in a new window or tab
            window.open(event.url,);
            return false;

          },


        defaultView: 'list',    
            nowIndicator: false, //show a marker for current time 
            eventLimit: 4, // allow "more" link when too many events
            fixedWeekCount: false, // have blank rows on a 6 or 7 row month
            listDayFormat: 'MMMM Do',
            listDayAltFormat: false,
            noEventsMessage: "No Currently Scheduled Events",
            views: {
                     list: {
                             duration: { days: 365 },
                            }
                    }
        })

    sources_to_load_cnt = ics_sources.length
    for (ics of ics_sources) {
        load_ics(ics)
    }
    add_recur_events()
})
```

Thanks.

[edit: removed extraneous backticks from answer.]